# R Shiny: alternate tabular data and plot visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dt

Please have a look at the simple Shiny app in the reprex.
My idea (and I am struggling to get it done with some switch statement) is to be able to use the button in the sidebar to select either only the table or only the line plot to be shown.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable



df <- tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20))


ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(

                         pickerInput("viz_type","Select what you want to see",
                        choices=(c("Tabular Data", "Line Plot")),
                        selected="Tabular Data",
                        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                       `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F)

         ),

         mainPanel(

    plotOutput("myplot" ,
               ) ,
    DTOutput("table")

             
)
         ))






server <- function(input, output) {

    compound_data <- reactive({
        df
        })

    output$table <- renderDT(compound_data())

    myplot <- reactive({

df1 <- compound_data()

gpl1 <- df1 %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
    


gpl1

})

    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        myplot()
        
    })

    
    }




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2021-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: See `conditionalPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `conditionalPanel` in the `ui`. Every widget, table, plot or text inside the panel is just shown when the criteria is met.

In your case the plot is shown when input$viz_type is "Line Plot" and the table is shown when input$viz_type equals "Tabular Data".

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

df <- tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20))


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      pickerInput("viz_type","Select what you want to see",
                  choices=(c("Tabular Data", "Line Plot")),
                  selected="Tabular Data",
                  options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                                 `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"),multiple = F)
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
    # Added conditions for showing Line Plot or Table
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.viz_type == 'Line Plot' ",
        plotOutput("myplot")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.viz_type == 'Tabular Data' ",
        DTOutput("table")
      )
      
    )
  ))






server <- function(input, output) {
  
  compound_data <- reactive({
    df
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(compound_data())
  
  myplot <- reactive({
    
    df1 <- compound_data()
    
    gpl1 <- df1 %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
      geom_point()
    
    
    
    gpl1
    
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    myplot()
    
  })
  
  
}




shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Example**
[image]

Comment: thanks, precisely what I was looking for! I was not aware of the existence of conditionalPanel.